# Waiting for an API request to end to call another function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue.js app I process user uploaded pictures with Google Vision API.

```
axios.post(`https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=${this.apiKey}`, axiosConfig)
        .then(response => {          
          let slicedLabelArray = response.data.responses[0].labelAnnotations.slice(0,5)
          slicedLabelArray.forEach(function(label) {
            let labelToAdd= label.description
            store.addLabels(labelToAdd)                 
          })
        })
```

I get the data I need but I have troubles setting up another function to be called right after my API request is done.

```
imageConversion () {
      console.log('converting')
      var byteString = atob(this.image.dataUrl.split(',')[1]);
      var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
      var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      var blob = new Blob([ia], {
        type: 'image/jpeg'
      });
      var file = new File([blob], "image.jpg");
      store.setFile(file)
    }
```

As soon I get the first 5 labels of my base64 image I need it to be converted. I know there is something call `promise` in JavaScript that could help me but in this case I can't find a proper way to use it.

My issue is that after the google Vision API request is done (and data is not yet returned), imageConversion() is executed and after that a `store.state` data is changed so a div with a button to upload the picture is displayed.

The purpose of the Google Vision Api call is to change the endpoint of where the picture is uploaded, depending of its label.

But if I don't wait for the response of the Google Vision API, I will have no endpoint to upload my picture.

So I want my Google Vision API to return the labels and only when they are returned, I want the other functions to be called.

Comment: Let me get it clear - You want another function to be called immediately after the API request is done. What's wrong with what you have tried so far?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Where is `imageConversion()` called, and what do you mean google vision API request is `done`, and data is not yet returned?

Comment: I mean that when I upload my picture to Google API it takes time for the API to process my picture and to send back the requested data (labels in my case)